# jQuery Textarea Selector Inside Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, textarea

I've the following piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />

    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="testForm" method="post" action="">
        <textarea id="test" rows="15" cols="60"></textarea>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="console.log($('#testForm :input').serializeArray());">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome console is printing an empty array, just like if #testForm :input selector is not selecting textarea. I'm looking for a way to select all form inputs and this works fine for other elements except textarea. How can I solve? Is serialize**Array** necessary or can I just use serialize method to send data to server?

Answer (score 1):

[.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) uses name of the input element to serialize, since your element does not have a name, it is omitted.

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for
>   successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in
>   particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name
>   attribute.

```
<textarea name="test" id="test" rows="15" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S5zyq/)

Answer (score 1):

For the `serializeArray()` method to work (and your HTML to be valid) you need to give the `textarea` a `name` attribute:

```
<form id="testForm" method="post" action="">
    <textarea id="test" rows="15" cols="60" name="foo"></textarea>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="console.log($('#testForm :input').serializeArray());">Send</button>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/D5Q5z/)

Answer (score 1):

`.serializeArray()` needs name attribute to create a array so insert name option

```
<textarea name="test" id="test" rows="17" cols="65"></textarea>
```